# Extracting Images from SD Card on Windows

Tags: raspbian, camera, image

I built a timelapse camera to watch over a construction project, and our internet connection is too spotty to transfer files by FTP.  The setup is on the side of the building accessible only by ladder (not a scissor lift or anything similar) and taking it all down to ground level would take more time than I wish to spend.

In the [worksheet](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/timelapse-setup/worksheet.md) it says that I can use copy the files from the SD card on a linux computer, can I do it on Windows?  I don't see any file structure when I plug the SD card into my laptop.

If I have to I will use FTP tonight on my extra Pi at home.

Comment: It depends to which partition you are writing the data. If the SD card, or partition, is formatted using ext2, ext3 or ext4 then Windows will not be able to read it, without a third party driver. Try [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/).  A quick google will show you how, [this for example](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  The default install (for example, if you used NOOBS to install Raspbian on your Pi) sets up the SD card with 2 partitions "boot" and "root".

"boot" is a small partition that contains files needed for boot.  It is formatted to be readable in most all PCs (Windows, Mac, Linux)

"root" contains all of Linux.  It is formatted to be readable in by Linux, and generally will take up the bulk of your SD card.   However, you can download software/drivers to make a Linux partition readable (and perhaps even writable) on Windows or other OSes.  For more info, Google something like:

https://www.google.com/search?q=read+linux+partition+on+windows